# how to return "sparse" json (choose a number of attributes ) from PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

MongoDB has a way of choosing the fields of a JSON documents that are returned as a result of query. I am looking for the same with PostgreSQL.

Let's assume that I've got a JSON like this:

```
{
a: valuea,
b: valueb,
c: valuec,
...
z: valuez
}
```

The particular values may be either simple values or subobjects with further nesting.

I want to have a way of returning JSON Documents containing only the atttributes I choose, something like:

```
SELECT json_col including_only a,b,c,g,n from table where...
```

I know that there is the `"-"` operator, allowing eliminating specific attributes, but is there an operator that does exactly the opposite?

Comment: You just build and return a new object with the selected values.

Comment: You can remove those you don't want using the `#-` or `-` operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In trivial cases you can use `jsonb_to_record(jsonb)`

```
with data(json_col) as (
values
('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}'::jsonb)
)

select *, to_jsonb(rec) as result
from data
cross join jsonb_to_record(json_col) as rec(a int, d int)

             json_col             | a | d |     result
----------------------------------+---+---+------------------
 {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4} | 1 | 4 | {"a": 1, "d": 4}
(1 row)
```

See [JSON Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

If you need a more generic tool, the function does the job:

```
create or replace function jsonb_sparse(jsonb, text[])
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select $1 - (
        select array_agg(key)
        from jsonb_object_keys($1) as key
        where key <> all($2)
        )
$$;

-- use:
select jsonb_sparse('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}', '{a, d}')
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bb4d2ae4577e7c31dc522bdacdfd300c)